# How can I determine the quality of service in WCF?

Tags: wcf, service, selection, qos

I want to determine the following QoS Attribute of my service:

1. Response Time
2. Reliability
3. Availability

I will be creating an application that will select a service based on the mentioned attribute.

Comment: What context? I mean, seriously - within a company? Just do it (keep logs etc., maybe expose quality of service through another WCF service). Internet? Hm, would be the firs ttime I could actually choose multiple service implementations for the same service.

Comment: I'm working on a study right now. I just need to know the mentioned attribute for service selection and composition. This is not a company implementation, it's just a school research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some or all of these attributes could be gleaned from switching on **diagnostics** for the service, but as this is likely to hurt performance, you may alternatively want to consider writing a few custom **performance counters** for your application.

Comment: Can you give me examples/scenarios in implementing the performance counter without switching on the diagnostic?

Comment: This is as good a place to start as any: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx